# EOFException on instantiation of a ObjectInputStream between two java processes

Tags: java, serialization, ipc

I'm experiencing some issues in having two java processes communicate via ObjectStreams; specifically an EOFException on instantiation of a ObjectInputStream. For my particular project the two processes in essence must be "piped" together, and I'm attempting to use these ObjectStreams in particular as an experiment in passing object-based messages between processes. After posting summarized example source of my two programs I will elaborate on what I've already attempted in solving the problem.

(If none of the above made sense I'll be editing the post again in the morning - I've been awake working on this problem for far too long)

### Driver.java - kicks off execution of Memory, CPU processes

```
 public class Driver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String filename = "file.txt"    // this is used to load 

            try {
                // start Memory.java as a separate child process
                Process memory = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java /path/to/Memory " + filename);
                System.out.println(memory.isAlive());

                // Set up "pipes" to Memory.java
                InputStream is = memory.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = memory.getOutputStream();

        System.out.println(memory.isAlive());
        System.out.println(memory);
        System.out.println(is);
        System.out.println(os);


                // pass the above streams and flow of execution to code in CPU.java
                com.company.CPU cpu = new com.company.CPU(is, os, interruptCount);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

### CPU.java -- inherits control from a call in driver.java

```
public class CPU {  
    ObjectInputStream input;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
CPU (InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        output.writeFloat(12.20f);
        System.out.println("CPU "+ input.readFloat());
        // output.writeObject(new Message("test", 1, 0));

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

### Memory.java -- runs as the child process initiated by .exec()

```
private static ObjectInputStream input;
private static ObjectOutputStream output;

/* We have a 'main' driving memory since it is an independent process */
public static void main(String args[]){
try { 
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
    output.writeFloat(10.10f);  
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));

    System.out.println("Memory "+ input.readFloat()); 

    /*
    Message instruction = (Message) input.readObject();
    while (instruction != null) { // process message as they come in

        *//*switch( instruction.getInstruction() ){

            case "read":

                break;
            case "write":

                break;
            case "exit": 

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Congrats, error");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException;
        }*//*
        instruction = (Message) input.readObject(); // tail
    }*/
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Memory-main (IOException): " + e);
    System.exit(-1);
}catch (other exceptions, etc...){}
}
```

### Message.java -- the passed object

```
class Message implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String instruction;  // read, write, exit
    private int arg1; // arg1
    private int arg2; // arg2

    Message(String inst, int x, int y ){/*assignments*/ } 
}
```

### Stack Trace

```
// first four lines are from Driver.java; they confirm process setup
    true
    java.lang.UNIXProcess@4769b07b
    java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@cc34f4d
    java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeOutputStream@17a7cec2
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2335)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
        at com.company.CPU.<init>(CPU.java:52)
        at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:66)
```

I've searched through many, many, posts; the only one that somewhat closely resembles my situation is as follows:
[EOFException while constructing an ObjectInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478176/eofexception-while-constructing-an-objectinputstream)

I've tried a bunch of stuff on my own (will elaborate tomorrow), I've tried everything to OP tried *before* posting to SO, I tried OP's and other's suggested solution, and even tried using sockets instead of InputStreams and OutputStreams as a separate mean of IPC to no avail. I'm consistently getting stuck on `input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));` and can't seem to find a workaround.

It's as if I'm not able to feed the pipes such that the receiving end will instantiate without throwing EOF. I realize that's the signal for end of stream and should be handled, but that's not the concern. The concern is actually transporting an object across the pipe